# How to link with a local ocaml library using dune

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-dune

I took over an ocaml project that consists of a main program and a library, but the library is built indepenently. Linking the main program was up until now possible with "ocamlopt -I  mylib.cmxa myprogram.ml" - but I had problems using opam libraries with ocamlopt so I decided to move to "dune" instead.

My question is: How do I link with the ocaml library using dune so that the result is the same like the ocamlopt line above did?

Answer (score 1):

It would help to see the structure of your project. However, in general if you have a project structured like this:

```
root/
|—— dune-project
|—— lib/
|  |—— dune
|  |—— lib.ml
|
|—— bin/
|  |—— dune
|  |—— bin.ml
```

Then your `lib/dune` will look something like

```
(library
 (name        mylib)
 (public_name mylib)
 (libraries core async))
```

and your `bin/dune` will simply list this library among its dependencies

```
(executable
 (name mybin)
 (libraries mylib))
```

For further guidance, consult the [`hello_world` example project](https://github.com/ocaml/dune/tree/master/example/sample-projects/hello_world) in the `dune` repository.